# Which RxSwift operator to use for uniquely emitted elements and how to?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

```
location.filter({$0.speed < 25})
.debounce(.seconds(20), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
.subscribe(onNext: { (location) in
    print(location)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**Goals:**

1. If the speed property remains below `25 for 20 seconds` then print location
2. If `within 20` seconds speed goes `above 25` cancel the emitted event
3. If the speed remains `below 25` for 40 seconds, location should be printed twice once at 20 seconds and again at 40 seconds.

Current problem is : If the speed goes below 25 and within 20 seconds observable receives a second event with speed below 25 it cancels out the previous event because of `debounce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the distinctUntilChanged operator:

```
location.distinctUntilChanged { $0.speed < 25 && $1.speed < 25 }
    .debounce(.seconds(20), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .filter { $0.speed < 25 }
    .subscribe(onNext: { location in
        print(location)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**EDIT**
Case when location should be printed every 20 seconds if speed is less than 25:

```
let isSpeedBelow = location
    .distinctUntilChanged { $0.speed < 25 && $1.speed < 25 }
    .flatMapLatest { location -> Observable<Double> in
        if location.speed >= 25 {
            return Observable.just(location)
        }
        return Observable<Int>.timer(.seconds(10), period: nil, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .map { _ in location.speed }
    }
    .map { $0 < 25 }
    .startWith(true)

Observable<Int>.timer(.seconds(10), period: .seconds(10), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .withLatestFrom(isSpeedBelow)
    .filter { $0 }
    .withLatestFrom(location)
    .subscribe(onNext: { location in
        print(location)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: If the speed remains below 25 for 40 seconds, the location should be printed twice. Once at 20 seconds and again at 40 seconds.

Will it work then?

Comment: @DaniyalRaza Then you should use timers. I have edited the answer, please check it